# ByeBug Debugger working only once [Rails 4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, byebug

I'm having the problem that byebug class are ignored after the first one. It's very strange.
I start the server. Whenever there is a byebug statement, if it is the first one since the server has started, it will work. If not, it will say this message: `*** Byebug already started. Ignoring`byebug`call.` and  the only way for the debugger to work would be to restart the server (and it will only work once).

Any help would be really appreciated.

BTW, this happens with every project.

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem, for what it's worth, but have not yet had a chance to come up with a minimal test case to file a bug report.

Comment: It's very strange. Are you using Ubuntu 14.04 by any chance ? I installed it a few days ago and didn't have this problem before.

Comment: Yep 14.04 here also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been [reported and fixed](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/issues/131), but isn't in a release yet.

To work around for now you update your `Gemfile` with:

```
gem 'byebug', github: 'deivid-rodriguez/byebug', branch: 'master'
```

Then `bundle update byebug` and restart your Rails server.

Comment: For the record, it is in a release now - so you can `bundle update byebug` and get version 4.0.5 with the fix.